# Facebook Android Integration Error

Tags: android, facebook

I am facing a problem when logging into Facebook using my app, It shows following error

**"App Not Setup : The Developer of this App have not setup this app properly for facebook login "**

This is my code :

```
package com.example.dronacharyaratings;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class login extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener  {

        ImageButton imgbtn;
        // Your Facebook APP ID
         private static String APP_ID = "578242662259998"; // Replace with your App ID

         // Instance of Facebook Class
         @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
         @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused" })
        private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
         String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
         private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

         @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")                   
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState1) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState1);
         setContentView(R.layout.login);
         getSupportActionBar().hide();

         mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

         imgbtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
         imgbtn.setOnClickListener(this);


     }


    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
        loginToFacebook();

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void loginToFacebook() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
          String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
          long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

          if (access_token != null) {
           facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);


           Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
          }

          if (expires != 0) {
           facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
          }

          if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
           facebook.authorize(this,
             new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
             new DialogListener() {

              @Override
              public void onCancel() {
               // Function to handle cancel event
              }

              @Override
              public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
               // Function to handle complete event
               // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
               editor.putString("access_token",
                 facebook.getAccessToken());
               editor.putLong("access_expires",
                 facebook.getAccessExpires());
               editor.commit();

               }


            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

             });
          }
    }

     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     }

     /**
      * Function to show Access Tokens
      * */
     public void showAccessTokens() {
      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    String access_token = facebook.getAccessToken();

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Access Token: " + access_token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issues only arises when your app isn't public.

- To do that you should first login into your
  [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com)
- and in the ***status and review*** of    your particular app
- Toggle the button to **yes** where it says "Do you want to make
  this app    and all its live features available to the general
  public? "

Comment: This answer should be marked as accepted !
Another hint: Make sure the key-hash is well set (with the release key-store's key hash for any released app).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error probably because your app is not public and only you as an admin have the access to login.For making the app as public and allowing others to use your app do the following steps.
1)Make sure you have a valid email in the "Contact Email" field in the settings -> Basic section.
2)Once you provide a valid e-mail then only you can make your app as public so that FB can contact you regarding your app.
3)In the "Status and Review" section change the option of "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" from "no" to yes and press confirm on the popup message.
you can see a red dot just next to your app name which confirms that your app is now available to public and all can login with their own credentials.
Happy facebooking!!!